# LINQPad query not working in EF

Tags: linq-to-entities, foreign-keys, entity-framework-5, linqpad

I created a query in LINQPad that looks like this:

```
from c in CashDrawers
join cd in CashDrawerActivities on c.Id equals cd.CashDrawerId into joinedT
from j in joinedT.DefaultIfEmpty()
group joinedT by c into g
select new
{
    StoreId = g.Key.StoreId,
    StoreName = g.Key.Store.Name,
    CashDrawer = g.Key,
    TotalAmount = g.Key.CashDrawerActivities.Any() ? g.Key.CashDrawerActivities.Select(x => (decimal)x.Amount).Sum () : 0
}
```

It works exactly as I wanted, so I copied it into my EF Code First project (with some tweaks):

```
from c in _context.Set<CashDrawer>()
join cd in  _context.Set<CashDrawerActivity>() on c.Id equals cd.CashDrawerId into joinedT
     from j in joinedT.DefaultIfEmpty()
     group joinedT by c into g
     select new
    {
     StoreId = g.Key.StoreId,
     StoreName = g.Key.Store.Name,
     CashDrawer = g.Key,
     TotalAmount = g.Key.CashDrawerActivities.Any() ? g.Key.CashDrawerActivities.Select(x => (decimal)x.Amount).Sum () : 0
   }
```

Now I get a compilation error:

```
'Domain.Entities.CashDrawer' does not contain a definition for 'CashDrawerActivities' and no extension method 'CashDrawerActivities' accepting a first argument of type 'Domain.Entities.CashDrawer' could be found
```

Which I understand as there is no FK relationship, but what I don't understand is why LINQPad was perfectly happy with the query.  Is there something else I need to do to make it work in EF? If not, LINQPad isn't much use to me!

Comment: Have you tried g.Key.CashDrawerActivity rather than .Key.CashDrawerActivities ?

Comment: @sgmoore - Same error, but related to `CashDrawerActivity`